# Installing zlib using stack: recompile with -fPIC

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When I run

```
stack --resolver=lts-7.14 install zlib
```

I'm getting message saying that package should be recompiled with `-fPIC` flag:

```
Configuring zlib-0.6.1.2...
Building zlib-0.6.1.2...
Preprocessing library zlib-0.6.1.2...
/usr/bin/ld: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-1.24.0.0/build/Codec/Compression/Zlib/Stream_hsc_make.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

How to tell stack to recompile `zlib` with `-fPIC` flag?

---

I added ghc-options to yaml file:

```
ghc-options:
  zlib: -fPIC

apply-ghc-options: locals
rebuild-ghc-options: true
```

Also, I added `-fPIC` flag to ghc-options in cabal file.

But still, I'm getting the same output:

```
--  While building package zlib-0.6.1.2 using:
  /home/vladimir/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.24.0.0_ghc-8.0.1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-nopie/Cabal-1.24.0.0 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/vladimir/Desktop/ffmpeg-light/.stack-work/logs/zlib-0.6.1.2.log
```

Where ghc-options are `-ddump-hi` and `-ddump-to-file` and no `-fPIC`. Did I miss something?

---

#### GCC, stack and OS versions:

GCC: gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005

Stack: Version 1.3.0, Git revision 99b910d3c8e183aa376cb1e6f0341d86aed6d00e (4372 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.15.0

OS: Ubuntu 16.10

---

Looks like it is [bug](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2711).

#### I found a hack:

I replaced

```
("C compiler flags", "-fno-PIE -fno-stack-protector")
```

by

```
("C compiler flags", "-fPIC -fno-stack-protector")
```

in file

```
/home/you/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.1/lib/ghc-8.0.1/settings
```

Now it compiles and works. I tested it on my project.

Comment: Try `--ghc-options -fPIC`, and/or check the stack FAQ.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2711) What stack / gcc version you are using, and what OS?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis updated question

Comment: @ppb indeed, I found hack there: changing ghc settings in .stack from `("C compiler flags", "-fno-PIE -fno-stack-protector")` to `("C compiler flags", "-fPIC -fno-stack-protector")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in how Cabal invokes hsc2hs. You need commit https://github.com/haskell/cabal/commit/c993a0c6660aa10d8c79ed0cc4961c59acfc91c8 which is present as of Cabal 1.24.1.0.